# IDEA: How to transform composite String to StringBuilder?

Tags: intellij-idea

Given

```
String s = "a" + "b" + "c";
```

Is it possible to transform it to

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder().append("a").append("b").append("c");
```

Comment: Even if there was, why would you do that? It is much optimized to have `"a" + "b"` than using a `StringBuilder` because the compiler does that for you anyway. IntelliJ does have a shortcut to go from a static `StringBuilder` to using `+` using the `alt+enter` shortcut.

Comment: Alt-Enter does not show this option, for this example

Comment: As I said, IntelliJ only goes from `StringBuilder` to `+`, not for the example you have.

Comment: Here is what I mean, http://cl.ly/image/3M471C3d0M1p. Plus I am using the EAP version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an intention for this, called *Replace '+' with 'StringBuilder.append()'*.

At least, it's offered to me - I'm using IDEA 12 EAP (Early Access Program).
You can get it here: [IDEA 12 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12+EAP)

The intention is offered when the caret is on the concatenated sequence, not from the String variable declaration itself.

Of course, after the transformation IDEA will inform you that such an *append()* sequence is silly, and will offer to simplify to a regular concatenation without any downsides.

Comment: This feature is not yet offered in IDEA 11.1.4.

Comment: Exactly, why it replaces clean append calls with a single line with a bunch of "foo" + getSomething() + "bar" ... ";` is insanity. I can see if you weren't making any method calls but that's a dumb way to do it or recommendation to begin with.